# Display associated product price in custom phtml file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom phtml file loaded via local.xml file. In this file I am displaying few products.Some of the products displaying are grouped products. SO I want to show the least tier price of these product.How can I get the least tier price?

Comment: can you share the code you are using