# Magento Contact form in ajax

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a Contact form on the footer of my site. The form is loaded from contacts module( i.e contacts->form.phtml). When clicked on submit button it sends the mail but directs me to  'http://www.example.com/contacts/index/' . Instead of directing me to this page is it possible to send mail via ajax and stay on same page? Please help me..I am on top of this for more than a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this without ajax , you need to modify `

> public function postAction() in
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

and in this function replace

```
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

with

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

it will do your work without ajax , from which ever page you will submit  form it will redirect you on same page after submit .

thanks and let me know if you have any problems in this.

Comment: That worked in not redirecting.But I did not receive any mail. :(

Comment: it has nothing to do with mail , may be it is some another problem check without this modification that mail works or not  or wait for some time to check mail

Comment: yes I checked without modifying and that worked fine.

Comment: This trick worked for me.Thanks Rohit..! Mail was not sending due smtp error.Now its working fine.

Comment: welcome :) i was also wondering that that has nothing to do with the mail but good to hear that it works for you now.

Comment: Rohit could you please help me on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018962/display-associated-product-price-in-custom-phtml-file